# AEAT-SII - ¿Podemos consumir servicio web SII pasando XML como cadena o XMLdocument?

Tags: vb.net, xml, aeat-sii

Estoy trabajando en la llamada de servicio web SII (Suministro Inmediato de Informacion) para "Facturas Emitidas" (SuministroLRFacturasEmitidas). A continuación se muestra cómo estamos trabajando

- El archivo XML se generará desde un sistema diferente y estará disponible en una ubicación.
- El servicio web (en el que estoy trabajando) leerá el archivo, se autenticará mediante el certificado y enviará la fecha al SII.
- Soy capaz de leer el archivo XML y autenticar usando el certificado. **Pero no estoy seguro de si puedo enviar XML como cadena o XMLdocument a SII.**

Me temo que tengo que analizar el archivo XML, extraer todos los valores de nodo, y luego pasar todas esas propiedades.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

También estoy con este tema y por lo que he podido comprobar no se puede enviar el xml asociado como cadena ni como archivo, sin embargo en el portal de pruebas si lo puedes hacer, que pasará a producción a partir del 1 de Julio:

http://www.agenciatributaria.es/AEAT.internet/Inicio/Ayuda/Modelos__Procedimientos_y_Servicios/Ayuda_P_G417____IVA__Llevanza_de_libros_registro__SII_/Ayuda_tecnica/Informacion_tecnica_SII/Preguntas_tecnicas_frecuentes/1__Cuestiones_Generales/28__Como_utilizar_el_cliente_de_web_service_en_el_entorno_de_pruebas_.shtml

La forma de enviar los datos sería **llamando a las funciones del webservice** una vez conectes vía soap, y estas funciones esperan datos del tipo struct, es decir que la creación y envío de xml ahora mismo no está operativa a través del webservice.

Comment: Gracias por el enlace

Comment: No se si es que no se ha entendido bien la pregunta / respuesta. Lo que @ManishKamdi quiere hacer es.. 1) Una aplicación externa genera el fichero XML y 2) Desde vb.net conectarse con el SII y enviar los datos de ese archivo, no? Pues yo entiendo qué si sería posible, aunque no usando cliente de webservice sino usando peticiones POST a esa URL. En este link está un ejemplo con `vba/vbs` https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/88257/modelo-sii-enviar-datos-al-web-service-usando-vba/131445#131445 y dudo que no se pueda hacer lo mismo con `vb.net`.