# Modelo SII: Enviar datos al Web Service usando vba

Tags: webservice, vba, aeat-sii

Intento conectar al Web Service de la AEAT (SII) para enviar ficheros XML.
Llevo un tremendo tiempo de investigación y pruebas, pero estoy muy cerca del abandono, o posponerlo hasta que haya mas información en la red

Para el envío, estoy intentando utilizar la librería SERVERXMLHTTP
Este sería el código:

```
Dim oWS As MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP
Set oWS = New MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP 
Dim xmlResponse As MSXML2.DOMDocument

'Abrimos conexión'
oWS.Open "POST", strURL, False
oWS.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"

'Autentificación'       
oWS.SetOption SXH_OPTION_SELECT_CLIENT_SSL_CERT,

'Envío'
Call oWS.send(strXml)
```

Cabe destacar que strURL es una ruta correcta y verificada, y strXML es un XML correcto

La respuesta que puedo ver es:
(Añado respuesta TEXTO completa al final de la consulta)

```
oWS.Status      'Respuesta = 200 (OK)'
oWS.ResponseXML 'Esta respuesta está vacía'
oWS.ResponseText 'Aquí hay un html que vendría a ser un formulario en el que me piden que entre la Cl@ve Pin'.
```

En resumen, lo que me parece faltar es el certificado digital. Quizás no sepa como llamar al certificado, pero ya he probado de mil maneras y no consigo saber como podría hacer uso de ello:

Opción 1: 
Según pude leer, si no especificamos el certificado, se selecciona el primero que haya (en mi caso solo tengo un certificado instalado a conciencia, pero puedo entender que me esté cogiendo alguna otra cosa

```
oWS.SetOption SXH_OPTION_SELECT_CLIENT_SSL_CERT, ""
```

Opción 2:
Muchas personas hablaban de buscar el registro al estilo: MY\
Dicha información es muy abstracta para mi.
Conseguí ver que los certificados se encuentran en el registro en estas rutas:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\MY\Certificates\
'Y allí dentro hay un directorio con muchos números y letras:'
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\...\Certificates\A1234C5678950E8F4295EA63D9515E3689B8EBC1
'Y dentro de ella hay una clave llamaada <Blob>'
```

Sabiendo esto, intenté varias aproximaciones:

```
oWS.SetOption SXH_OPTION_SELECT_CLIENT_SSL_CERT, "LOCAL_MACHINE\MY\A1234C5678950E8F4295EA63D9515E3689B8EBC1"
oWS.SetOption SXH_OPTION_SELECT_CLIENT_SSL_CERT, "LOCAL_MACHINE\MY\Certificates\A1234C5678950E8F4295EA63D9515E3689B8EBC1"
oWS.SetOption SXH_OPTION_SELECT_CLIENT_SSL_CERT, "LOCAL_MACHINE\MY\Certificates\A1234C5678950E8F4295EA63D9515E3689B8EBC1\Blob"
```

Opción 3:
También pude leer que se debía especificar el nombre CN del certificado 
sxh.setOption(3) = "Common Name (CN) part of certificate's Subject name"

```
'Nombre completo que pude encontrar en CN:'
oWS.SetOption SXH_OPTION_SELECT_CLIENT_SSL_CERT, "PEPITO GRILLO - 39301234P"
'Parte del nombre que pude encontrar en CN:'
oWS.SetOption SXH_OPTION_SELECT_CLIENT_SSL_CERT, "39301234P"
'Nombre completo CN, pero añadiendo la ruta'
oWS.SetOption SXH_OPTION_SELECT_CLIENT_SSL_CERT, "LOCAL_MACHINE\MY\PEPITO GRILLO - 39301234P"
```

En fin... mil maneras de intentar localizar y poder usar el certificado. Pero ninguna me funcionó. La respuesta siempre es la misma.

**Quizás me estoy equivocando en algo?**

El certificado pude localizarlo de varias maneras

```
> MMC.exe
 > Archivo > Agregar o quitar complementos...
  > Certificados (Equipo local)

> FIREFOX
 > Opciones > Avanzado... > Certificados > Ver Certificados...
  > Sus Certificados:
   > FNMT-RCM
    > PEPITO GRILLO - 39301234P
```

En ambos casos podemos localizar los certificados. Y una vez localizado, si hacemos doble clic sobre el certificado, aparece toda la información, como por ejemplo el CN que intenté usar en la opción 3, o la secuencia de numeros y letras que encontré en le registro (el valor de la Huella digital SHA1 es lo que había en el registro de Windows)

Saliendo un poco de vba, tengo un apunte final:

Debido a que no conseguí hacerlo funcionar, intenté usar CURL.EXE. No entraré en detalle por ahora en como envié los datos, pero si que la respuesta que me dió llegó a ser la misma (respuesta que reenvía a un formulario donde tener que entrar la Cl@ve Pin"

En resumen, algo no hago bien porque no capta mis certificados, pero no se como solucionarlo.

APÉNDICE 1: Añado respuesta TEXTO que me devuelve el intento de envío a la AEAT:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html lang="es" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="es">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-15" />
<title>Autenticaci&oacute;n - Cl@ve PIN</title>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
<link href="/static_files/common/css/xzhtcs04.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="/static_files/common/internet/dep/aplicaciones/ov/css/p24idecs.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static_files/common/internet/dep/aplicaciones/ov/script/aeatrsc0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static_files/common/internet/dep/aplicaciones/ov/script/p24a01cd.js"></script>
<script src="/static_files/common/internet/script/clave_pin.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
jQuery.noConflict();
var ref = "/wlpl/SII-FACT/ws/fe/SiiFactFEV1SOAP";
var from = '';
var bfprint = '&amp;BFPRINT;';
var storksp = '';
var qaa = '';
var msg = '';
//]]>
</script>
</head>
<body onload="init();" onfocus="focoEnPagina();">
        <!-- p24Aut01.html -->
        <div id="AEAT_header"></div>
        <div id="p24h-pane" class="AEAT_contenedor">
        <div id="p24h-title" class="AEAT_contenedor">
            <h2>Autenticaci&oacute;n</h2>
        </div>
        <div id="qaa-2" style="display:none;text-align: right;font-size: xx-small;">Nivel b&aacute;sico</div>
        <div id="qaa-3" style="display:none;text-align: right;font-size: xx-small;">Nivel sustancial</div>
        <!-- div class="AEAT_bloque_avisos p24h-avisos">
            <h2>Avisos:</h2>
            <p>Para el correcto funcionamiento del servicio Cl@ve PIN es necesario que su navegador permita la utilizaci&oacute;n
                de cookies y la ejecuci&oacute;n de javascript</p>
        </div-->
        <div id="errores" class="AEAT_bloque_errores p24h-errores" style="display: none"></div>
        <div id="avisos" class="AEAT_bloque_avisos p24h-avisos" style="display: none"></div>
        <div id="p24h-form" class="AEAT_contenedor">    
            <form id="iden-form" name="iden-form" action="/es12/l/es02genp24h1" method="post" class="AEAT_form" autocomplete="off">
                    El asterisco <span class="obligatorio"> * </span> indica que es imprescindible completar este dato<br/><br/>

                    <table id="p24h-campos" class="ancho_100">
                        <tr id="campo-nif"><td class="ancho_25" style="text-align: right">
                            <label for="nif">
                                    <span class="obligatorio">* </span><acronym title="Documento Nacional de Identidad">DNI</acronym>/<acronym title="N&uacute;mero de Identificaci&oacute;n de Extranjero">NIE</acronym>
                            </label></td>
                            <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <input type="text" id="nif" name="NIF" size="9em" maxlength="9" placeholder="DNI/NIE" style="width: 11ex" value="" onblur="chequearNIF();$('msg-nif').hide();" onfocus="activarMsg('msg-nif');"/>
                            <span id="msg-nif" style="display: none">&laquo; Introduzca el <acronym title="Documento Nacional de Identidad">DNI</acronym>/<acronym title="N&uacute;mero de Identificaci&oacute;n de Extranjero">NIE</acronym></span>
                        </td></tr>
                        <tr id="campo-ape" style="display: none"><td class="ancho_25" style="text-align: right">
                            <span class="obligatorio">* </span>&nbsp;<label for="ape">Primer apellido</label>
                        </td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <input type="text" id="ape" name="APE" size="20em" maxlength="20" placeholder="Primer Apellido" style="width: 22ex" value="" onfocus="activarMsg('msg-ape');" onblur="$('msg-ape').hide();"/>
                            <span id="msg-ape" style="display: none">&laquo; Introduzca su primer apellido</span>
                        </td></tr>                      
                        <tr id="campo-clv">
                            <td class="ancho_25" style="text-align: right">
                                <label for="clv"><span class="obligatorio">* </span>C&oacute;digo</label>
                            </td>
                            <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                <input type="text" id="clv" name="CLV" size="4em" maxlength="4" value="" placeholder="Clave" style="width: 5ex" onfocus="$('clv').select();activarMsg('msg-clv');" onblur="$('msg-clv').hide();"/>
                                <span id="msg-clv" style="display: none">&laquo; Introduzca el c&oacute;digo elegido en el proceso de obtenci&oacute;n</span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="campo-pin">
                            <td class="ancho_25" style="text-align: right">
                                <label for="pin"><span class="obligatorio">* </span><acronym title="N&uacute;mero Personal de Identificaci&oacute;n">PIN</acronym></label>
                            </td>
                            <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                <input type="password" id="pin" name="PIN" size="3em" maxlength="3" value="" placeholder="PIN" style="width: 5ex" onfocus="$('pin').select();activarMsg('msg-pin');" onblur="$('msg-pin').hide();"/>
                                <span id="msg-pin" style="display: none">&laquo;  Introduzca el <acronym title="N&uacute;mero Personal de Identificaci&oacute;n">PIN</acronym> que ha recibido en su tel&eacute;fono m&oacute;vil. Estar&aacute; compuesto por letras (excluida la eñe) y/o d&iacute;gitos (excluidos el cero, uno, ocho y nueve).</span>
                                <!--span id="msg-pin" style="display: none">&laquo; Introduzca el <acronym title="N&uacute;mero Personal de Identificaci&oacute;n">PIN</acronym> que ha recibido en el <acronym title="Servicio de Mensajer&iacute;a Corta">SMS</acronym></span-->
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    <!-- Opcional. Número de teléfono -->
                        <tr id="campo-tmv" style="display: none"><td class="ancho_25" style="text-align: right">
                            <label for="tmv"><span class="obligatorio">* </span>Tel&eacute;fono m&oacute;vil</label>
                        </td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <input id="tmv" name="TMV" size="15em" maxlength="15" placeholder="tel&eacute;fono m&oacute;vil" style="width: 17ex" value="" onfocus="activarMsg('msg-tmv');" onblur="$('msg-tmv').hide()"/>
                            <span id="msg-tmv" style="display: none">&laquo; Introduzca el n&uacute;mero de tel&eacute;fono con el que di&oacute; de alta el servicio <acronym title="Servicio de autenticaci&oacute;n por PIN de 24 horas">PIN</acronym></span>
                        </td></tr>
                    </table>
            <div id="botones" class="AEAT_bloque_botones p24-botones">
                    <input type="button" id="boton-acceder"   class="AEAT_boton" value="Acceder" onclick="acceder('es');"/>
                    <input type="button" id="boton-solicitar" class="AEAT_boton" value="No tengo PIN" onclick="solicitudDePin('es');"/>
                    <input type="button" id="boton-acceso-registro" class="AEAT_boton" value="No estoy registrado" onclick="accederRegistroClave('es');"/>
            </div>
            <!-- ATENCIÓN: El orden es significativo -->
            <input type="hidden" id="ref" name="REF" value="/wlpl/SII-FACT/ws/fe/SiiFactFEV1SOAP"/><!-- referrer que me pasa la infraestructura del CWS -->
            <input type="hidden" id="from" name="FROM" value=""/><!-- origen de la petición actual, para stork -->
            <input type="hidden" id="bfprint" name="BFPRINT" value="&amp;BFPRINT;"/><!-- firgerprint del usuario -->
            <input type="hidden" id="storksp" name="STORKSP" value="&amp;STROKSP;"/><!-- origen de la petición actual, para stork -->
            <input type="hidden" id="qaa" name="QAA" value=""/><!-- qaa solicitado desde el SP (Proveedor de servicios) -->
            <input type="hidden" id="msg" value=""/><!-- mensage que me pasa la infraestructura del CWS --> 
            <input type="hidden" id="idi" value="es"/><!-- idioma en el que se encuentra la página -->
            </form>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div id="p24h-registro-clave" title="Registro en Cl@ve" style="display:none">
            <p>La Administración Estatal ha implantando el sistema <strong class="azul">Cl@ve</strong>, que permite el acceso sencillo a los
            servicios electrónicos de diferentes administraciones públicas.</p>
            <p>Si quiere beneficiarse de esta plataforma, s&oacute;lo ser&aacute; necesario que se d&eacute; de alta en un
            registro &uacute;nico. Una vez registrado en <strong class="azul"> Cl@ve </strong> podr&aacute; utilizar algunos de los sistemas de
            identificaci&oacute;n y autenticaci&oacute;n que forman parte de la plataforma, para acceder a los
            diferentes servicios de administraci&oacute;n electr&oacute;nica que se han integrado en la plataforma,
            y sin necesidad de contar con diferentes altas en cada servicio.</p>
            <p>Los sistemas que permiten la identificaci&oacute;n  al acceder a los servicios electr&oacute;nicos
            son el sistema Cl@ve PIN y el sistema Cl@ve Permanente. Para m&aacute;s informaci&oacute;n sobre las
            caracter&iacute;sticas de estos sistemas, visite <a href="http://clave.gob.es/">
            clave.gob.es</a>.</p>
            <p>Los sistemas que forman parte de <strong class="azul">Cl@ve</strong> permiten cubrir las diferentes necesidades y
            circunstancias de los ciudadanos que necesitan realizar tr&aacute;mites administrativos y de
            los &oacute;rganos u organismos que los ofrecen a trav&eacute;s de sus Sedes Electr&oacute;nicas.</p>
            <p>A partir del 1 de enero de 2016, el sistema PIN24H desaparece para integrarse definitivamente
            en Cl@ve PIN. Como usuario registrado del sistema PIN24H, puede incorporar sus datos
            a la nueva plataforma <strong class="azul">Cl@ve</strong> de forma sencilla. Si usted desea beneficiarse de las ventajas
            que ofrece esta nueva plataforma, por favor haga clic en <em>registrarse en Cl@ve</em> y le guiaremos en el proceso.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="p24h-aviso-tdp" title="Importante:" style="display: none">
            <p>Se ha detectado que el n&uacute;mero de tel&eacute;fono m&oacute;vil que constaba asociado al
            <acronym title="Documento Nacional de Identidad">DNI</acronym>/<acronym title="N&uacute;mero de Identificaci&oacute;n de Extranjero">NIE</acronym>
            indicado se encuentra actualmente asignado a otro usuario del sistema <strong class="azul"> Cl@ve </strong>.</p>
            <p>Por su seguridad, para poder recibir el <acronym title="N&uacute;mero Personal de Identificaci&oacute;n">
            PIN</acronym> v&iacute;a <acronym title="Servicio de Mensajer&iacute;a Corta">SMS</acronym> y continuar con el tr&aacute;mite es
            necesario que actualice su n&uacute;mero de tel&eacute;fono.</p>
            <p>Esta actualizaci&oacute;n se puede realizar presencialmente en una Oficina de Registro de usuarios de la plataforma
            <strong class="Azul"> Cl@ve </strong> o de forma telem&aacute;tica con certificado o <acronym title="Documento Nacional de Identidad">DNI</acronym>
            electr&oacute;nico en la Sede Electr&oacute;nica de la Agencia Estatal de Administraci&oacute;n Tributaria. La relaci&oacute;n de
            Oficinas de Registro se encuentra publicada en el Portal <a href="http://administracion.gob.es">Punto de Acceso General</a>.</p>

        </div>
        <div id="p24h-error-bfp" title="Atenci&oacute;n" style="display:none">
            <p>Se ha detectado una modificaci&oacute;n en las caracter&iacute;sticas del dispositivo desde el que est&aacute; intentando
            acceder al sistema <strong class="azul"> Cl@ve </strong> <acronym title="N&uacute;mero Personal de Identificaci&oacute;n">PIN</acronym>.</p>
            <p>Por su seguridad, para continuar con el tr&aacute;mite es necesario que obtenga un nuevo
            <acronym title="N&uacute;mero Personal de Identificaci&oacute;n">PIN</acronym>.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="p24h-fuera-de-servicio" title="Aplicaci&oacute;n fuera de servicio" style="display:none">
            <p id="msg-fuera-servicio"></p>
        </div>
        <!-- para ponerlos disponibles en la página que llama a registro previos -->
        <div id="p24h-datos" style="display: none">
            <input type="hidden" id="extrainfo" value=""/>
        </div>      
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    /*
    * Si el parámetro entorno es "", activarFueraDeServicio no hace nada.
    */
    //activarFueraDeServicio({entorno: "PRO",dia: "2016-11-16",desde: "14.30.00"});
    /* Prioridad en el tratamiento de los lenguajes
     * 1.- valor de la cookie aeat-language
     * 2.- variable id en la queryString
     * 3.- valor de la cabecera accept-language
     */
    var qs = location.search.toQueryParams();
    if ($('idi').value == 'es') {
        /* solo se realiza la redirección desde la página en español */
        var aeatLanguage = AEAT.getCookie("aeat-language");
        var acceptLanguage = window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language;
        var idi = qs.idi;

        var qstr = "?ref=" + encodeURIComponent(unescape($('ref').value.stripTags())) + "&msg=" + $('msg').value ;
        var h = $H(qs);
        h.each(function(pair){  
            if (pair.key != 'ref') {
                qstr = qstr + "&" + pair.key + "=" + pair.value;
            }
        });
        var value = "";
        if (aeatLanguage != null && aeatLanguage != undefined) {
            value = aeatLanguage;
        } else if (idi != null && idi != undefined) {
            value = idi;
        } else if (acceptLanguage != null && acceptLanguage != undefined){
            value = acceptLanguage;
        }

        switch (value.substring(0,2)) {
            case "ca":
            case "CA":
            case "ca_ES" : location.href="/es13/h/p24autc1.html"+qstr;break;
            case "gl":
            case "GL":
            case "gl_ES" : location.href="/es13/h/p24autg1.html"+qstr;break;
            case "va":
            case "VA":
            case "va_ES" : location.href="/es13/h/p24autv1.html"+qstr;break;
            default: break;
        }
    }

    /* para el resto de los los idiomas (no español) */
    $('ref').value = (qs.ref != undefined) ? decodeURIComponent(unescape(qs.ref.stripTags())) : "/wlpl/SII-FACT/ws/fe/SiiFactFEV1SOAP";
    $('msg').value = (qs.msg != undefined) ? qs.msg : "";
    $('from').value = (qs.from != undefined) ? qs.from : "";
    $('storksp').value = (qs.storksp != undefined) ? qs.storksp: "";
    $('qaa').value = (qs.qaa != undefined) ? qs.qaa : "";

    var bfp = new Fingerprint().get({screen_resolution: true, ie_activex: true});
    $('bfprint').value = AEAT.rjust(""+bfp,10,'0');
    //]]>
</script>
<noscript>
<!-- código para mostrar mensaje de javascript y/o cookies desactivadas -->
<div class="ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ui-dialog-title-avisoCookiesDesactivadas" style="display: block; z-index: 1002; outline: 0px; height: auto; width: 500px; top: 361.5px; left: 37%;">
    <div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix">
        <span class="ui-dialog-title" id="ui-dialog-title-avisoCookiesDesactivadas">Aviso</span>
        <a href="#" class="ui-dialog-titlebar-close ui-corner-all" role="button"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-closethick">close</span></a>
    </div>
    <div id="avisoCookiesDesactivadas" class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" scrolltop="0" scrollleft="0" style="width: auto; min-height: 30.8px; height: auto;">
        <div class="AEAT_bloque_errores">
            <p>Para el correcto funcionamiento de la Sede Electr&oacute;nica es necesario que su navegador permita la utilizaci&oacute;n de cookies y de javascript.</p>
            <p>Si no sabe como hacerlo puede consultarlo en el siguiente enlace: </p>
            <p>
                <a class="enlace_no_decorado negrita" href="http://www.agenciatributaria.es/AEAT.internet/Ayuda/config_Sede.shtml" target="blank">
                Requisitos t&eacute;cnicos para realizar tr&aacute;mites en la Sede Electr&oacute;nica
                </a>
            </p>
            <p>Para mas informaci&oacute;n sobre las cookies visite la <a class="enlace_no_decorado negrita"
                href="https://www.agenciatributaria.gob.es/AEAT.sede/Inicio/_pie_/_Aviso_Legal_/_Aviso_Legal_.shtml" target="blank">
                pol&iacute;tica de privacidad</a>.
            </p>
            <br/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="ui-widget-overlay" style="height: 955px; z-index: 1001;"></div>
</noscript>
</html>
```

Comment: Buenas BeniGls, bienvenido a [es.so]. Increible pregunta, suerte encontrando solucion :D  Mientras tanto no olvides pasar por el [tour] para aprender cómo funciona el sitio. Para más información tienes [ask], [help] y [Meta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/). Un saludo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontré el siguiente código en https://community.softwaregrp.com/t5/UFT-Practitioners-Forum/xmlhttp-send-request-is-not-completing-for-soap-call/td-p/242616

Y le hice unas pequeñas modificaciones, concretamente definir algunas variables que faltaba definir y colocar un nombre de certificado que tengo instalado en la maquina.

```
Dim strURLEndpoint
Dim strContentType
Dim strSOAPAction
Dim strCertificaatNaam
Dim objRequestXML

objRequestXML="aqui va el xml"

strURLEndpoint="https://www7.aeat.es/wlpl/SSII-FACT/ws/fe/SiiFactFEV1SOAP"
strSOAPAction="test"

'Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP setOption variables
Const SXH_OPTION_URL                                   = -1
Const SXH_OPTION_URL_CODEPAGE                        = 0
Const SXH_OPTION_ESCAPE_PERCENT_IN_URL                = 1
Const SXH_OPTION_IGNORE_SERVER_SSL_CERT_ERROR_FLAGS = 2

Const SXH_SERVER_CERT_IGNORE_UNKNOWN_CA         =    256        'Unknown certificate authority
Const SXH_SERVER_CERT_IGNORE_WRONG_USAGE        =    512        'Malformed certificate such as a certificate with no subject name
Const SXH_SERVER_CERT_IGNORE_CERT_CN_INVALID    =    4096    'Mismatch between the visited hostname and the certificate name being used on the server
Const SXH_SERVER_CERT_IGNORE_CERT_DATE_INVALID    =    8192    'The date in the certificate is invalid or has expired.\
Const SXH_SERVER_CERT_IGNORE_ALL_SERVER_ERRORS    =    13056    'All certificate errors

Const SXH_OPTION_SELECT_CLIENT_SSL_CERT                = 3

Set objWinHttp = CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP")
strContentType ="text/XML;charset=UTF-8" 'Web Service Content Type

'Open HTTP connection
objWinHttp.Open "POST", strURLEndpoint, False

'Setting Request Headers
objWinHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", strContentType
objWinHttp.setRequestHeader "SOAPAction", strSOAPAction

'    objWinHttp.setOption SXH_OPTION_IGNORE_SERVER_SSL_CERT_ERROR_FLAGS, SXH_SERVER_CERT_IGNORE_ALL_SERVER_ERRORS
objWinHttp.setOption SXH_OPTION_IGNORE_SERVER_SSL_CERT_ERROR_FLAGS, SXH_SERVER_CERT_IGNORE_CERT_CN_INVALID

'Setting the clientcertificate (Optional)
strCertificaatNaam="ALEXANDRU CATALIN TRANDAFIR - X4378072E"
If UCase(strCertificaatNaam) <> "" AND  UCase(strCertificaatNaam) <> "[SKIP]" Then
    objWinHttp.setOption SXH_OPTION_SELECT_CLIENT_SSL_CERT, strCertificaatNaam
End If

'Send SOAP request
objWinHttp.Send objRequestXML

msgbox objWinHttp.ResponseText
```

Ellos usan muchas opciones de parametrización sin embargo las que importan creo que son:

```
Const SXH_OPTION_SELECT_CLIENT_SSL_CERT                = 3
```

Y también:

```
'Setting the clientcertificate (Optional)
strCertificaatNaam="ALEXANDRU CATALIN TRANDAFIR - X4378072E"
If UCase(strCertificaatNaam) <> "" AND  UCase(strCertificaatNaam) <> "[SKIP]" Then
    objWinHttp.setOption SXH_OPTION_SELECT_CLIENT_SSL_CERT, strCertificaatNaam
End If
```

En este caso se puede ver que he indicado `ALEXANDRU CATALIN TRANDAFIR - X4378072E` como nombre de certificado, y es que en Mozilla Firefox tengo instalado un certificado con ese nombre.

Pantallazo 1:

[image: Mozilla Certificado]

Y pantallazo con respuesta:

[image: Respuesta petición]

Y bien, en la respuesta se puede ver que la petición se ha realizado correctamente, es decir, ha podido usar el certificado y ahora se queja de que el XML no es válido.

No es mi entorno preferido por lo que si estas familiarizado con PHP y con ese lenguaje te serviría para tu aplicación, [te recomiendo este ebook técnico de implementación del SII](http://www.aeatsiidesarrolladores.es/) donde hay ejemplos en php de todo el circuito de comunicación.

### ACTUALIZACIÓN: Comunicación completa con el SII, con llamada y respuesta XML

Después de haber realizado la prueba del certificado, modifiqué el código para conseguir comunicar debidamente unas facturas de prueba y aquí coloco todos los ficheros:

El script `test.vbs`:

```
Dim strURLEndpoint
Dim strContentType
Dim strSOAPAction
Dim strCertificaatNaam
Dim objRequestXML

Dim fso

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set file = fso.OpenTextFile("datos_xml.txt", 1)
objRequestXML = file.ReadAll

msgbox objRequestXML

strURLEndpoint="https://www7.aeat.es/wlpl/SSII-FACT/ws/fe/SiiFactFEV1SOAP"
strSOAPAction="SuministroLRFacturasEmitidas"

'Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP setOption variables
Const SXH_OPTION_URL                                   = -1
Const SXH_OPTION_URL_CODEPAGE                        = 0
Const SXH_OPTION_ESCAPE_PERCENT_IN_URL                = 1
Const SXH_OPTION_IGNORE_SERVER_SSL_CERT_ERROR_FLAGS = 2

Const SXH_SERVER_CERT_IGNORE_UNKNOWN_CA         =    256        'Unknown certificate authority
Const SXH_SERVER_CERT_IGNORE_WRONG_USAGE        =    512        'Malformed certificate such as a certificate with no subject name
Const SXH_SERVER_CERT_IGNORE_CERT_CN_INVALID    =    4096    'Mismatch between the visited hostname and the certificate name being used on the server
Const SXH_SERVER_CERT_IGNORE_CERT_DATE_INVALID    =    8192    'The date in the certificate is invalid or has expired.\
Const SXH_SERVER_CERT_IGNORE_ALL_SERVER_ERRORS    =    13056    'All certificate errors

Const SXH_OPTION_SELECT_CLIENT_SSL_CERT                = 3

Set objWinHttp = CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP")
strContentType ="text/XML;charset=UTF-8" 'Web Service Content Type

'Open HTTP connection
objWinHttp.Open "POST", strURLEndpoint, False

'Setting Request Headers
objWinHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", strContentType
objWinHttp.setRequestHeader "SOAPAction", strSOAPAction

'    objWinHttp.setOption SXH_OPTION_IGNORE_SERVER_SSL_CERT_ERROR_FLAGS, SXH_SERVER_CERT_IGNORE_ALL_SERVER_ERRORS
objWinHttp.setOption SXH_OPTION_IGNORE_SERVER_SSL_CERT_ERROR_FLAGS, SXH_SERVER_CERT_IGNORE_CERT_CN_INVALID

'Setting the clientcertificate (Optional)
strCertificaatNaam="ALEXANDRU CATALIN TRANDAFIR - X4378072E"
If UCase(strCertificaatNaam) <> "" AND  UCase(strCertificaatNaam) <> "[SKIP]" Then
    objWinHttp.setOption SXH_OPTION_SELECT_CLIENT_SSL_CERT, strCertificaatNaam
End If

'Send SOAP request
objWinHttp.Send objRequestXML

msgbox objWinHttp.ResponseText

Set objFile = fso.CreateTextFile("respuesta.txt",True)
objFile.Write objWinHttp.ResponseText & vbCrLf
objFile.Close
```

El fichero con los datos de la llamada, `datos_xml.txt`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="https://www2.agenciatributaria.gob.es/static_files/common/internet/dep/aplicaciones/es/aeat/ssii/fact/ws/SuministroInformacion.xsd" xmlns:ns2="https://www2.agenciatributaria.gob.es/static_files/common/internet/dep/aplicaciones/es/aeat/ssii/fact/ws/SuministroLR.xsd">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns2:SuministroLRFacturasEmitidas>
      <ns1:Cabecera>
        <ns1:IDVersionSii>1.0</ns1:IDVersionSii>
        <ns1:Titular>
          <ns1:NombreRazon>ALEXANDRU CATALIN TRANDAFIR</ns1:NombreRazon>
          <ns1:NIF>X4378072E</ns1:NIF>
        </ns1:Titular>
        <ns1:TipoComunicacion>A0</ns1:TipoComunicacion>
      </ns1:Cabecera>
      <ns2:RegistroLRFacturasEmitidas>
        <ns1:PeriodoImpositivo>
          <ns1:Ejercicio>2017</ns1:Ejercicio>
          <ns1:Periodo>12</ns1:Periodo>
        </ns1:PeriodoImpositivo>
        <ns2:IDFactura>
          <ns1:IDEmisorFactura>
            <ns1:NIF>X4378072E</ns1:NIF>
          </ns1:IDEmisorFactura>
          <ns1:NumSerieFacturaEmisor>SIIDEMO/1</ns1:NumSerieFacturaEmisor>
          <ns1:FechaExpedicionFacturaEmisor>31-12-2017</ns1:FechaExpedicionFacturaEmisor>
        </ns2:IDFactura>
        <ns2:FacturaExpedida>
          <ns1:TipoFactura>F1</ns1:TipoFactura>
          <ns1:FechaOperacion>31-12-2017</ns1:FechaOperacion>
          <ns1:ClaveRegimenEspecialOTrascendencia>01</ns1:ClaveRegimenEspecialOTrascendencia>
          <ns1:ImporteTotal>1210</ns1:ImporteTotal>
          <ns1:DescripcionOperacion>Compra ordenador portátil</ns1:DescripcionOperacion>
          <ns1:Contraparte>
            <ns1:NombreRazon>HeavyDots SL</ns1:NombreRazon>
            <ns1:NIF>B66544586</ns1:NIF>
          </ns1:Contraparte>
          <ns1:TipoDesglose>
            <ns1:DesgloseFactura>
              <ns1:Sujeta>
                <ns1:NoExenta>
                  <ns1:TipoNoExenta>S1</ns1:TipoNoExenta>
                  <ns1:DesgloseIVA>
                    <ns1:DetalleIVA>
                      <ns1:TipoImpositivo>21</ns1:TipoImpositivo>
                      <ns1:BaseImponible>500</ns1:BaseImponible>
                      <ns1:CuotaRepercutida>105</ns1:CuotaRepercutida>
                    </ns1:DetalleIVA>
                    <ns1:DetalleIVA>
                      <ns1:TipoImpositivo>21</ns1:TipoImpositivo>
                      <ns1:BaseImponible>500</ns1:BaseImponible>
                      <ns1:CuotaRepercutida>105</ns1:CuotaRepercutida>
                    </ns1:DetalleIVA>
                  </ns1:DesgloseIVA>
                </ns1:NoExenta>
              </ns1:Sujeta>
            </ns1:DesgloseFactura>
          </ns1:TipoDesglose>
        </ns2:FacturaExpedida>
      </ns2:RegistroLRFacturasEmitidas>
      <ns2:RegistroLRFacturasEmitidas>
        <ns1:PeriodoImpositivo>
          <ns1:Ejercicio>2017</ns1:Ejercicio>
          <ns1:Periodo>12</ns1:Periodo>
        </ns1:PeriodoImpositivo>
        <ns2:IDFactura>
          <ns1:IDEmisorFactura>
            <ns1:NIF>X4378072E</ns1:NIF>
          </ns1:IDEmisorFactura>
          <ns1:NumSerieFacturaEmisor>SIIDEMO/2</ns1:NumSerieFacturaEmisor>
          <ns1:FechaExpedicionFacturaEmisor>31-12-2017</ns1:FechaExpedicionFacturaEmisor>
        </ns2:IDFactura>
        <ns2:FacturaExpedida>
          <ns1:TipoFactura>F1</ns1:TipoFactura>
          <ns1:FechaOperacion>31-12-2017</ns1:FechaOperacion>
          <ns1:ClaveRegimenEspecialOTrascendencia>01</ns1:ClaveRegimenEspecialOTrascendencia>
          <ns1:ImporteTotal>1210</ns1:ImporteTotal>
          <ns1:DescripcionOperacion>Compra ordenador portátil</ns1:DescripcionOperacion>
          <ns1:Contraparte>
            <ns1:NombreRazon>HeavyDots SL</ns1:NombreRazon>
            <ns1:NIF>B66544586</ns1:NIF>
          </ns1:Contraparte>
          <ns1:TipoDesglose>
            <ns1:DesgloseFactura>
              <ns1:Sujeta>
                <ns1:NoExenta>
                  <ns1:TipoNoExenta>S1</ns1:TipoNoExenta>
                  <ns1:DesgloseIVA>
                    <ns1:DetalleIVA>
                      <ns1:TipoImpositivo>21</ns1:TipoImpositivo>
                      <ns1:BaseImponible>500</ns1:BaseImponible>
                      <ns1:CuotaRepercutida>105</ns1:CuotaRepercutida>
                    </ns1:DetalleIVA>
                    <ns1:DetalleIVA>
                      <ns1:TipoImpositivo>21</ns1:TipoImpositivo>
                      <ns1:BaseImponible>500</ns1:BaseImponible>
                      <ns1:CuotaRepercutida>105</ns1:CuotaRepercutida>
                    </ns1:DetalleIVA>
                  </ns1:DesgloseIVA>
                </ns1:NoExenta>
              </ns1:Sujeta>
            </ns1:DesgloseFactura>
          </ns1:TipoDesglose>
        </ns2:FacturaExpedida>
      </ns2:RegistroLRFacturasEmitidas>
    </ns2:SuministroLRFacturasEmitidas>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

El fichero donde se ha escrito la respuesta recibida, `respuesta.txt`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <env:Header />
   <env:Body Id="Body">
      <siiR:RespuestaLRFacturasEmitidas xmlns:siiR="https://www2.agenciatributaria.gob.es/static_files/common/internet/dep/aplicaciones/es/aeat/ssii/fact/ws/RespuestaSuministro.xsd" xmlns:sii="https://www2.agenciatributaria.gob.es/static_files/common/internet/dep/aplicaciones/es/aeat/ssii/fact/ws/SuministroInformacion.xsd">
         <siiR:Cabecera>
            <sii:IDVersionSii>1.0</sii:IDVersionSii>
            <sii:Titular>
               <sii:NombreRazon>ALEXANDRU CATALIN TRANDAFIR</sii:NombreRazon>
               <sii:NIF>X4378072E</sii:NIF>
            </sii:Titular>
            <sii:TipoComunicacion>A0</sii:TipoComunicacion>
         </siiR:Cabecera>
         <siiR:EstadoEnvio>Incorrecto</siiR:EstadoEnvio>
         <siiR:RespuestaLinea>
            <siiR:IDFactura>
               <sii:IDEmisorFactura>
                  <sii:NIF>X4378072E</sii:NIF>
               </sii:IDEmisorFactura>
               <sii:NumSerieFacturaEmisor>SIIDEMO/1</sii:NumSerieFacturaEmisor>
               <sii:FechaExpedicionFacturaEmisor>31-12-2017</sii:FechaExpedicionFacturaEmisor>
            </siiR:IDFactura>
            <siiR:EstadoRegistro>Incorrecto</siiR:EstadoRegistro>
            <siiR:CodigoErrorRegistro>3000</siiR:CodigoErrorRegistro>
            <siiR:DescripcionErrorRegistro>Factura duplicada</siiR:DescripcionErrorRegistro>
            <siiR:CSV>QSAYUMZV8NM3REGD</siiR:CSV>
         </siiR:RespuestaLinea>
         <siiR:RespuestaLinea>
            <siiR:IDFactura>
               <sii:IDEmisorFactura>
                  <sii:NIF>X4378072E</sii:NIF>
               </sii:IDEmisorFactura>
               <sii:NumSerieFacturaEmisor>SIIDEMO/2</sii:NumSerieFacturaEmisor>
               <sii:FechaExpedicionFacturaEmisor>31-12-2017</sii:FechaExpedicionFacturaEmisor>
            </siiR:IDFactura>
            <siiR:EstadoRegistro>Incorrecto</siiR:EstadoRegistro>
            <siiR:CodigoErrorRegistro>3000</siiR:CodigoErrorRegistro>
            <siiR:DescripcionErrorRegistro>Factura duplicada</siiR:DescripcionErrorRegistro>
            <siiR:CSV>QSAYUMZV8NM3REGD</siiR:CSV>
         </siiR:RespuestaLinea>
      </siiR:RespuestaLRFacturasEmitidas>
   </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Comment: Tu ejemplo me funcionó a la perfección. Y me sirvió para detectar el problema que había en mi código, y para comprender el uso del certificado
En un día has resuelto dos de las vías que intentaba utilizar para realizar envíos. Mil gracias, era una espina que no creí poder resolver nunca :D

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que el problema, como dicen está en el certificado, en alguna ocasión también me dió problemas el MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP, ¿has podido probar otro?.
¿Has podido contactar con alguien en AEAT?, es posible que otros usuarios tengan las mismas consecuencias. Recomendarte también usar postman o aplicación similar para probar la solución sin programar desde el equipo cliente, para descartar otro tema.

¿has visto este hilo?:

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28114300/cant-connect-to-server-over-https-which-uses-a-sha2-certificate-using-msxml2-se)

Por último recomendarte que intentes preguntar en stackoverflow en inglés, por lo poco que he podido ver por aquí se está más preocupado por como se responde que ayudar a la pregunta :)

Comment: Respecto a la AEAT, la única respuesta que saben dar es que debido a la gran cantidad de dudas no pueden ayudarnos en aspectos técnicos de este estilo. Probé con WinHttp.WinHttpRequest y con MSXML2.XMLHTTP, pero nada. Instalé SoapUI para testear. El testeo fue bien. En SoapUI hay una opción en preferencias para cargar certificado (SSL Settings > Key Store). Ahi pude cargar un certificado .p12, el cual exporté desde el navegador. Probé a encontrar la manera de usar ese certificado con la librería que usaba (y con las otras), pero no vi manera de sacarle provecho.

Comment: Respecto al link, no lo había visto, aunque no veo claro que pueda servirme. También busqué información en inglés, y probé todo lo que pude encontrar. Me decanté por preguntar en este foro en español porque el modelo SII es específico en España, y tenía la muy diluida esperanza de que alguien se encontrara con algo similar en este mismo escenario del SII